# Composing two functions in lua

Tags: function, lua

I just started learning lua, so what I'm asking might be impossible.

Now, I have a method that accepts a function:

```
function adjust_focused_window(fn)
  local win = window.focusedwindow()
  local winframe = win:frame()
  local screenrect = win:screen():frame()
  local f, s = fn(winframe, screenrect)
  win:setframe(f)
end
```

I have several functions that accept these frames and rectangles (showing just one):

```
function full_height(winframe, screenrect)
   print ("called full_height for " .. tostring(winframe))
  local f = {
     x = winframe.x,
     y = screenrect.y,
     w = winframe.w,
     h = screenrect.h,
  }
  return f, screenrect
end
```

Then, I can do the following:

```
hotkey.bind(scmdalt, '-', function() adjust_focused_window(full_width) end)
```

Now, how could I compose several functions to `adjust_focused_window`, without changing it's definition. Something like:

```
hotkey.bind(scmdalt, '=', function() adjust_focused_window(compose(full_width, full_height)) end)
```

where `compose2` would return a function that accepts the same parameters as `full_width` and `full_height`, and internally does something like:

```
full_height(full_width(...))
```

Comment: function compose2(f1, f2) return function(...) return f1(f2(...)) end end

Comment: Thanks @moteus, that works like I charm. I had to change what full_height/width returns in order to be able to chain them (reflected now in my question).

Comment: question =~ s/might be impossible/might be simple and I should study more/;

Comment: @moteus if it works for him can you put it as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, to chain two functions together you can just do:

```
function compose(f1, f2)
  return function(...) return f1(f2(...)) end
end
```

But what if you want to connect more than 2 functions together? You might ask, is it possible to 'compose' an arbitrary number of functions together?

The answer is a definite yes -- below I show 3 different approaches for implementing this plus a quick summary of their consequences.

### Iterative Table approach

The idea here is to call each function in the list one after the other in turn. While doing so, you save the returned results from the previous call into a table and you unpack that table and pass it into the next call.

```
function compose1(...)
    local fnchain = check_functions {...}
    return function(...)
        local args = {...}
        for _, fn in ipairs(fnchain) do
            args = {fn(unpack(args))}
        end
        return unpack(args)
    end
end
```

The `check_functions` helper above just checks that the stuff passed in are indeed functions -- raises an error if not. Implementation omitted for brevity.

**+**: Reasonably straight-forward approach. Probably what you'd come up with on a first attempt.

**-**: Not very efficient on resources. A lot of garbage tables to store results between calls. You also have to deal with packing and unpacking the results.

### Y-Combinator Pattern

The key insight here is that even though the functions we're calling isn't recursive, it can be made recursive by piggy-backing it on a recursive function.

```
function compose2(...)
  local fnchain = check_functions {...}
  local function recurse(i, ...)
    if i == #fnchain then return fnchain[i](...) end
    return recurse(i + 1, fnchain[i](...))
  end
  return function(...) return recurse(1, ...) end
end
```

**+**: Doesn't create extra temporary tables like above. Carefully written to be tail-recursive -- that means no extra stack space needed for calls to long function chains. There's a certain elegance to it.

### Meta-script generation

With this last approach, you use a lua function that actually generates the exact lua code that performs the function call chain desired.

```
function compose3(...)
    local luacode = 
    [[
        return function(%s)
            return function(...)
                return %s
            end
        end
    ]]
    local paramtable = {}
    local fcount = select('#', ...)
    for i = 1, fcount do
        table.insert(paramtable, "P" .. i)
    end
    local paramcode = table.concat(paramtable, ",")
    local callcode = table.concat(paramtable, "(") ..
                     "(...)" .. string.rep(')', fcount - 1)
    luacode = luacode:format(paramcode, callcode)
    return loadstring(luacode)()(...)
end
```

The `loadstring(luacode)()(...)` probably needs some explaining. Here I chose to encode the function chain as parameter names (`P1, P2, P3` etc.) in the generated script. The extra `()` parenthesis is there to 'unwrap' the nested functions so the inner most function is what's returned. The `P1, P2, P3 ... Pn` parameters become captured upvalues for each of the functions in the chain eg.

```
function(...)
  return P1(P2(P3(...)))
end
```

Note, you could also have done this using `setfenv` but I chose this route just to avoid the breaking change between lua 5.1 and 5.2 on how function environments are set.

**+**: Avoids extra intermediate tables like approach #2. Doesn't abuse the stack.

**-**: Needs an extra byte-code compile step.

Comment: thanks for a detailed answer and listing the pros/cons of each of the answers, this helps in learning lua!

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the passed functions, successively invoking the next function in the chain with the results from the previous.

```lua
function module._compose(...)
  local n = select('#', ...)
  local args = { n = n, ... }
  local currFn = nil

  for _, nextFn in ipairs(args) do
    if type(nextFn) == 'function' then
      if currFn == nil then
        currFn = nextFn
      else
        currFn = (function(prev, next)
          return function(...)
            return next(prev(...))
          end
        end)(currFn, nextFn)
      end
    end
  end

  return currFn
end
```

Note the use of [Immediately Invoked Function Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression) above, which allow the re-used function variables to not invoke an infinite recursive loop, which happens in the following code:

```lua
function module._compose(...)
  local n = select('#', ...)
  local args = { n = n, ... }
  local currFn = nil

  for _, nextFn in ipairs(args) do
    if type(nextFn) == 'function' then
      if currFn == nil then
        currFn = nextFn
      else
        currFn = function(...)
          return nextFn(currFn(...)) -- this will loop forever, due to closure
        end
      end
    end
  end

  return currFn
end
```

Although Lua doesn't support ternary operators, [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) can be used to remove the inner `if` statement:

```lua
function module.compose(...)
  local n = select('#', ...)
  local args = { n = n, ... }
  local currFn = nil

  for _, nextFn in ipairs(args) do
    if type(nextFn) == 'function' then
      currFn = currFn and (function(prev, next)
        return function(...)
          return next(prev(...))
        end
      end)(currFn, nextFn) or nextFn
    end
  end

  return currFn
end
```