# Recursively calling the functions in lua

Tags: function, lua, circular-buffer

I am working on a script. The script includes some functions. Every function has one url packet that query the server. The server returns the data in JSON format. To use this data I have included the JSON library.

The problem I am facing is each function calls the next function after it finishes executing its body.

Like:

```
When Function1 Finishes it calls function2
when Function2 Finishes it calls Function3...and so on
```

So in-between if one of the function fails the script stops executing further.

I have research about this on Google and found out that i have to implement a circular buffer but couldn't find any good example of it.

One of my friend pointed out me that call functions recursively is very bad idea. Is that right?

Comment: It sound like your question is similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/q/27170825/234175.

Comment: @celeritas When improving a lua-tagged question, please make sure to update "LUA" to "lua" or "Lua".

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're talking about a ring buffer. You can find an example implementation [here](http://mmom.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/classIV/server/simulator/temp/ringbuffer.lua).